# What can I do to make my code more efficient and not use global variables

Tags: python, variables, scope, global, coding-efficiency

So today I built a very simple number guessing game and the below code is what I wrote. I understand that it's incredibly inefficient and I use global too much, which is generally known as a bad practice. What advice would you give to me, a beginner in Python, to overcome this problem?

```
import random

print(logo)
print("Heya! Welcome to Bull's Eye Number!")

global lives
lives = 0
global game_ended
game_ended = False
global selected_number
selected_number = random.randint(1,100)
global player_guess
player_guess = 0

def select_difficulty():
  global lives
  player_difficulty = input("Alright! To start, select a difficulty,'Easy' or 'Hard': ")
  if player_difficulty == "Easy":
    lives = 10
  elif player_difficulty == "Hard":
    lives = 5

def make_a_guess():
  global player_guess
  player_guess = int(input("What do you think the number might be?:  "))

def adjust_lives():
  global selected_number
  global lives
  if not player_guess == selected_number:
    lives -= 1
    print(f"You now have {lives} lives left")

  
def check_game_ended():
  global game_ended
  global selected_number
  if lives == 0:
    game_ended = True
    print(f"Oh no! You didn't manage to guess it. The number was {selected_number}. Better luck next time!")
  elif player_guess == selected_number: 
    game_ended = True
    print(f"You guessed it right! The number was infact {selected_number}")

def evaluate_guess():
  global player_guess
  global selected_number
  if player_guess > selected_number:
    print("Your guess was a bit too High.")
  elif player_guess < selected_number:
    print("Your guess was a bit too Low")

select_difficulty()
print(f"You've got {lives} lives to start! ")
while game_ended == False:
  make_a_guess()
  evaluate_guess()
  adjust_lives()
  check_game_ended()
```

Comment: consider asking on [codereview.stackexchane.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: " I understand that it's incredibly inefficient " what do you mean by inefficient? Generally, when we talk about efficiency in the context of programming, we are talking about performance, i.e. runtime efficiency, memory efficiency. But as others have stated, this really isn't (as currently stated) on-topic for StackOverflow. Consider [codereview.se]

Comment: In general, though, the way to avoid mutable global state is to *pass in the values you require as arguments to your function* and *return values that you need to the caller*

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
def select_difficulty():
  player_difficulty = input("Select a difficulty,'Easy' or 'Hard': ")
  if player_difficulty == "Easy":
    return  10
  return 5

lives = select_difficulty()
```

Then pass lives as parameter to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need the `global` keyword at top-level code. The variables outside functions are `global` by default.
- To make your code cleaner you can utilize modules and/or classes. But if you want to have everything in one file, I don't see a problem with your code. Also, you can pass your variables to the functions and make them return their modified values if you don't want to use global variables.

Comment: " But if you want to have everything in one file, I don't see a problem with your code. " There is a huge problem, correctly identified by the OP: the code relies on mutable global state. This isn't a mere afterthought. Entire programming paradigms will not allow you to do this (indeed, eschewing all mutable state at all!) because it is considered such a pernicious problem

Comment: I disagree that mutating global state in such a small application is necessarily a bad thing. But yes, OP explicitly asked to eliminate this practice.

Comment: I mean, almost nothing is necessarily a bad thing in a small script. That doesn't really get around the larger point when we are talking about general best-practices when it comes to programming. *Generally* it is good to have variable names that are descriptive, but if I just want a quick script, I might just use `x`